# Create an array as a result of different arrays in C#

Tags: c#, matlab

I want to build a vector as a part of different vectors in C#

In Matlab would be:

```
arr1 = [1, 1, 1, 1];
arr2 = [2, 2, 3, 2, 2];

arr[1:2] = arr1[1:2];
arr[3:5] = arr2[2:4];
%arr = [1, 1, 2, 3, 2];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Array.Copy` to simulate behavior. But in Matlab arrays are 1-based, and in C# they are 0-based. Also you have to predefine the size of output array.

```
int[] arr1 = { 1, 1, 1, 1 };
int[] arr2 = { 2, 2, 3, 2, 2 };
int[] arr = new int[5];
Array.Copy(arr1, 0, arr, 0, 2);
Array.Copy(arr2, 1, arr, 2, 3);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", arr));
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double[] arr1= { 1, 1, 1, 1 };
        double[] arr2= { 2, 2, 3, 2, 2 };

        double[] res=arr1.Take(2).Concat(arr2.Skip(1).Take(3)).ToArray();
        // res = {1, 1, 2, 3, 2}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C# you would use a `List<T>` and the methods `AddRange()` or `InsertRange()`.

```
int[] l1 = { 1, 2 ,3 };
int[] l2 = { 2, 3, 4 };
List<int> res = new List<int>();
res.InsertRange(0, l1);
res.InsertRange(1, l2);
```

The result is: `1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3`

Comment: You also need the `.Skip()` and `.Take()` extension methods to filter what you need.

Comment: Or ``.Where()`` or ``.GetRange()``

Answer (score 0):

I supposed you can code up your own array class, with range indexing:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Array<double> arr1= new double[] { 1, 1, 1, 1 };
        Array<double> arr2= new double[] { 2, 2, 3, 2, 2 };

        Array<double> res=arr1[Index.Span(0, 2)]&arr2[Index.Span(1, 3)];
        // res = {1, 1, 2, 3, 2}
        Array<double> res2=2*res+1;
        // res2 = {3, 3, 5, 7, 5}
        Array<double> res3=res2.Apply(Math.Sqrt);
        // res3 = {√3, √3, √5, √7, √5}
    }
}
```

with the following array class:

```
/// <summary>
/// Generic Array object
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The element type</typeparam>
public class Array<T> : IEnumerable<T>, ICloneable
{
    readonly T[] elements;
    public Array(int count) { this.elements=new T[count]; }
    public Array(params T[] elements) { this.elements=elements; }
    public Array(IEnumerable<T> elements) { this.elements=elements.ToArray(); }
    public static implicit operator Array<T>(T element) { return new Array<T>(element); }
    public static implicit operator Array<T>(T[] elements) { return new Array<T>(elements); }
    public static implicit operator T[](Array<T> array) { return array.elements; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Concatenate two arrays
    /// </summary>
    public static Array<T> operator&(Array<T> array1, Array<T> array2)
    {
        return new Array<T>(array1.elements.Concat(array2.elements));
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Get a single element from the array
    /// </summary>
    public T this[int index]
    {
        get { return elements[index]; }
        set { elements[index]=value; }
    }
    public int Count { get { return elements.Length; } }
    /// <summary>
    /// Extract a sub-array based on the index range
    /// </summary>
    public Array<T> this[Index index]
    {
        get { return index.Extract(elements); }
        set { index.Inject(elements, value); }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Apply a transformation to the array
    /// </summary>
    public R[] Apply<R>(Func<T, R> unary) { return elements.Select((e) => unary(e)).ToArray(); }
    /// <summary>
    /// Combine two arrays using a binary operator
    /// </summary>
    public R[] Apply<T1, R>(Array<T1> other, Func<T, T1, R> binary) { return elements.Zip(other, binary).ToArray(); }

    /// <summary>
    /// Dynamic addition operator
    /// </summary>
    public static Array<T> operator+(Array<T> a, Array<T> b)
    {
        int N=Math.Max(a.Count, b.Count);
        T[] res=new T[N];
        for(int i=0; i<res.Length; i++)
        {
            res[i]=(dynamic)a[i%a.Count]+(dynamic)b[i%b.Count];
        }
        return res;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Dynamic subtraction operator
    /// </summary>
    public static Array<T> operator-(Array<T> a, Array<T> b)
    {
        int N=Math.Max(a.Count, b.Count);
        T[] res=new T[N];
        for(int i=0; i<res.Length; i++)
        {
            res[i]=(dynamic)a[i%a.Count]-(dynamic)b[i%b.Count];
        }
        return res;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Dynamic multiplication operator
    /// </summary>
    public static Array<T> operator*(Array<T> a, Array<T> b)
    {
        int N=Math.Max(a.Count, b.Count);
        T[] res=new T[N];
        for(int i=0; i<res.Length; i++)
        {
            res[i]=(dynamic)a[i%a.Count]*(dynamic)b[i%b.Count];
        }
        return res;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Dynamic division operator
    /// </summary>
    public static Array<T> operator/(Array<T> a, Array<T> b)
    {
        int N=Math.Max(a.Count, b.Count);
        T[] res=new T[N];
        for(int i=0; i<res.Length; i++)
        {
            res[i]=(dynamic)a[i%a.Count]/(dynamic)b[i%b.Count];
        }
        return res;
    }

    #region IEnumerable
    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        for(int i=0; i<elements.Length; i++) { yield return elements[i]; }
    }
    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
    #endregion

    #region ICloneable Members
    public Array<T> Clone() { return new Array<T>(elements); }
    object ICloneable.Clone() { return Clone(); }
    #endregion
}
```

which depends on the following range indexing structure:

```
/// <summary>
/// Array index range object
/// </summary>
public struct Index : IEnumerable<int>, ICloneable
{
    readonly int[] index_list;
    public Index(params int[] indeces) { index_list=indeces; Array.Sort(index_list); }
    public Index(IEnumerable<int> indeces) { index_list=indeces.ToArray(); Array.Sort(index_list); }
    /// <summary>
    /// Create a sequence of integers
    /// </summary>
    public static Index Span(int start, int count, int stride=1)
    {
        int[] values=new int[count];
        for(int i=0; i<values.Length; i++)
        {
            values[i]=start+i*stride;
        }
        return new Index(values);
    }
    public static implicit operator Index(int index) { return new Index(index); }
    public static implicit operator Index(int[] indeces) { return new Index(indeces); }
    public static implicit operator int[](Index index) { return index.index_list; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Concatenates two ranges. (1,2) & (5,6) => (1,2,5,6)
    /// </summary>
    public static Index operator&(Index i1, Index i2) { return new Index(i1.index_list.Concat(i2.index_list)); }
    /// <summary>
    /// Combines two ranges filling in the indegers inbetween. (1,2) | (5,6) => (1,2,3,4,5,6)
    /// </summary>
    public static Index operator|(Index i1, Index i2) { return i1&Span(i1.Max+1, i2.Min-i1.Max-1)&i2; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Extract a single index from range
    /// </summary>
    public int this[int index] { get { return index_list[index]; } }
    public int Count { get { return index_list.Length; } }
    /// <summary>
    /// Extract a range of indexes from range
    /// </summary>
    public int[] this[Index index]
    {
        get { return index.Extract(index_list); }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Lowest Index in Range
    /// </summary>
    public int Min { get { return index_list.Length>0?index_list[0]:-1; } }
    /// <summary>
    /// Highest Index in Range
    /// </summary>
    public int Max { get { return index_list.Length>0?index_list[index_list.Length-1]:-1; } }
    /// <summary>
    /// Extracts elements from an array based on the indexes in the range
    /// </summary>
    public T[] Extract<T>(T[] array)
    {
        T[] elements=new T[index_list.Length];
        for(int i=0; i<index_list.Length; i++)
        {
            elements[i]=array[index_list[i]];
        }
        return elements;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Injects elements int an array based on the indexes in the range
    /// </summary>
    public void Inject<T>(T[] array, T[] elements)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<index_list.Length; i++)
        {
            array[index_list[i]]=elements[i];
        }
    }

    #region IEnumerable
    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
    {
        for(int i=0; i<index_list.Length; i++) { yield return index_list[i]; }
    }
    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
    #endregion

    #region ICloneable Members
    public Index Clone() { return new Index(this.index_list); }
    object ICloneable.Clone() { return Clone(); }
    #endregion

}
```